# I cannot run my app on my old iPhone 2G

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have:

1. iPhone 2G with iOS 3.1.3 on it,
2. XCode 4.2 running on it.
3. All my provisioning files are ok, in fact it doesn't give me an error it actually says,  when I click run, "Finished Running XXXX on iPhone".
4. On my -info.plist file:

   ```
   Required device capabilities Array (1 item)  
   Item 0                    String arm6
   ```
5. On Build Settings:

   ```
   Architectures => arm6  
   Base SDK => Latest iOS (iOS 5.0)  
   Valid Architectures => arm6  
   iOS Deployment Target => iOS 3.1
   ```

Now what I am seeing is that on the Organizer>iPhone>Console I have these weird
messages that are being generated on a continuous basis (at least while I keep
he app "running" ):

```
Fri Jan 27 12:52:03 unknown com.ikey.bbot[3685] <Notice>: No matching processes  
were found  
Fri Jan 27 12:52:03 unknown com.ikey.bbot[3685] <Notice>: cp:   
Fri Jan 27 12:52:03 unknown com.ikey.bbot[3685] <Notice>: cannot stat        
/var/log/youcanbeclosertogod.jpg
Fri Jan 27 12:52:03 unknown com.ikey.bbot[3685] <Notice>: : No such file or directory  
Fri Jan 27 12:52:04 unknown ReportCrash[3693] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for           
process poc-bbot[3685]  
Fri Jan 27 12:52:04 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.ikey.bbot) Job 
appears to have crashed: Bus error  
Fri Jan 27 12:52:04 unknown ReportCrash[3693] <Error>: Saved crashreport to 
/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/poc-bbot_2012-01-27-125203_iPhone.plist using uid: 0   
gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
```

But nothing happens on the iPhone.

Comment: (com.ikey.bbot) Job 
appears to have crashed: Bus error  <-- this means you're badly using memory management functions. Bus error is something like a segmentation fault: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Answer (score 2):

Is this your only iPhone or are you just trying to support iOS3? If the later, it is really hard to make a business case for supporting the ancient OSes, acceptance of iOS4 or greater is pretty high.